# point a subdomain to a page without using domain module

Tags: 8, subsites

I want to add a subdomain to my site (mysite.local) so it is, x.mysite.local and I want that to land on a custom page, i.e. a node, a view. I do not want to use the domain module because it has way more stuff that I need. Is there an easy way to do that in a custom module?

I tried doing something like this in settings.php but that does not seem to work:

```
// Get the subdomain:
$sub = explode('.',  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])[0];
if ($sub == 'test') {
  $config['system.site']['page']['front'] = "node/12664";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume 1) you already have the proper DNS records set up and 2) you want a redirect (tells the browser to go to URL `node/12664`) and not a proxy rewrite (i.e. serve the page at `node/12664`).

Your best option would be to handle this in your .htaccess with mod_rewrite:

```
# Handle request for subdomain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.mysite\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://mysite.local/node/12664 [L,R]
```

If you do want to try to handle this as a redirect in your `settings.php` you could try something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == 'test.mysite.local') {
    // Tell the browser to redirect to the HTTPS URL.
    header("Location: https://mysite.local/node/12664");
    exit;
}
```

If you want to serve a page from a *different* subdomain/host, without changing the URL, you'll have to delve into the hell of Apache [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html)

Comment: Yes DNS is set up correctly. But I do not want to do any apache/.htaccess redirect. This should be possible to do by doing something similar to what the [domain access module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)  module does. But I have not been able to dig deep enough to figure out the peices of the code that does this.